# How to write a function which toggles between the executions of two other functions?

Tags: elisp

Suppose that we have two functions `foo1` and `foo2`. I would like to write a third function `foo3` in such a way that the first execution of `foo3`results in the execution of `foo1`, the second execution of `foo3` results in the execution of `foo2` and so on (i.e. the nth execution of `foo3` results in the execution of `foo1` if `n` is odd, and results in the execution of `foo2` if `n` is even).

Is this possible?

Comment: Since lisps are awesome, you could do something like this: https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/4918ac0043af4b3889fd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a state variable to keep track of which function you called most recently, and condition the call in the third function on its value:

```el
(defun fn1 ()
  (message "Function 1"))

(defun fn2 ()
  (message "Function 2"))

(defvar fn1-p nil)

(defun fn3 ()
  (setf fn1-p (not fn1-p))
  (funcall (if fn1-p #'fn1 #'fn2)))
```

**EDIT:** as per @politza's suggestion, here's a way to do the toggle with a closure (compare the example in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html#Lexical-Binding)):

```el
(setf lexical-binding t)                ; need to create a closure
(let (toggle)
  (setf fn4 (lambda ()
              (setf toggle (not toggle))
              (funcall (if toggle #'fn1 #'fn2)))))
(funcall fn4)                           ; => "Function 1"
(funcall fn4)                           ; => "Function 2"
(funcall fn4)                           ; => "Function 1"
```

Comment: Using a closure would be another option, depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is written to demonstrate the little-known [`ring`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html) data structure available in Emacs' built-ins:

```el
(defun function-1 () (print "Function 1"))

(defun function-2 () (print "Function 2"))

(defun function-3 () (print "Function 3"))

(defvar functions (let ((result (make-ring 3)))
                    (ring-insert result 'function-1)
                    (ring-insert result 'function-2)
                    (ring-insert result 'function-3)
                    result))

(defun cycle-functions ()
  (funcall
   (ring-insert functions
                (ring-ref functions
                          (1- (ring-size functions))))))

(with-output-to-string
  (cl-loop repeat 10 do (cycle-functions)))
"
\"Function 1\"

\"Function 2\"

\"Function 3\"

\"Function 1\"

\"Function 2\"

\"Function 3\"

\"Function 1\"

\"Function 2\"

\"Function 3\"

\"Function 1\"
"
```

The difference between this and other answers is that here you have the data structure to manipulate, which means that you can program a change in the order of execution of functions, whereas in other suggested answers this isn't an option. Whether you need that or not, is, of course, up to you.

Comment: Thanks, what `(with-output-to-string   (cl-loop for i below 10 do (cycle-functions)))...` actually does?

Comment: @Name `with-output-to-strintg` is a macro which binds the `*standard-output*` name buffer to a special buffer it creates, so that all text that you output using `print` and similar commands goes into that buffer. Then it returns the contents of that buffer. `(cl-loop ...)` simply calls the `cycle-functions` several times to generate some text printed from the functions it cycles through.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance I think I'd forgo using a separate variable or a lexical closure, and just use a property on the function symbol to track its own state.

Here's Dan's answer adapted to that approach:

```el
(defun fn1 ()
  (message "Function 1"))

(defun fn2 ()
  (message "Function 2"))

(defun fn3 ()
  (put 'fn3 'fn1-p (not (get 'fn3 'fn1-p)))
  (funcall (if (get 'fn3 'fn1-p) #'fn1 #'fn2)))
```

Comment: Nice!  Hadn't realized you could do that.  Tidier this way.

Comment: This would also depend on the use-case, of course. A variable may be more sensible for whatever the actual scenario is. This approach can be useful to know about, though.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's the kind of way this kind of thing is usually done in existing Elisp packages (tho for repeated interactive execution of a command rather than just for repeated calls to a function):

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq this-command last-command)
      (progn
        (setq this-command 'foo2)
        <foo2-behavior>)
    <foo1-behavior>))
```